# Can't hide labels and text boxes when button is checked

Tags: c#

When salaried button is checked,  change label "Hour Pay: " to "Salary" and hide the labels and text boxes below it. When Hourly button is checked, return everything to its initial form.

My main issue is when i execute code it does not hide labels and text boxes.

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void icontype_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (salariedRadioButton.Checked == true)
    {
        hourLabel.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (hourlyRadioButton.Checked == true)
    {
        hourLabel.Visible = true;
    }
}

private void hourTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        weekTextBox.Text =(float.Parse(hourTextBox.Text)40).ToString();
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    try
    {
        yearTextBox.Text = (float.Parse(weekTextBox.Text) 52).ToString();
    }
    catch 
    { 

    }
}
```

Comment: How specifically does this fail when you debug?  I assume this is a WinForms application?  When you check the checkbox, is `icontype_CheckedChanged` invoked?  When you step through it in the debugger, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your expected result, for the hide part, I think you can try this, thanks.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
                    
        this.salariedRadioButton.CheckedChanged += icontype_CheckedChanged;
        this.hourlyRadioButton.CheckedChanged += icontype_CheckedChanged;
    }        

    private void icontype_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (salariedRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            hourLabel.Visible = false;
            weekTextBox.Visible = false;
        }
        else if(hourlyRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            hourLabel.Visible = true;
            weekTextBox.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```